# Can't mount USB flash drives or my CD/DVD drives

Tags: 12.10, permissions, usb-drive, chmod, cd-drive

How can I fix the permissions to get rid of the following error and mount my USB and internal CD/DVD drive:

```
Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to `/media/bret' failed: Operation not supported
```

These drives worked fine in 12.04, but I apparently now don't have permissions to mount these drives in 12.10. I tried `chmod` in the terminal, but I couldn't enter as the superuser, so I seem to be stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If becoming superuser is the only problem, then do

```
sudo su root
```

(a user who has proper privileges can use sudo to become superuser using her/his own password.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an answer to this problem. I posted a question, which wasn't answered. But I've just found some info - its a bug that has been reported - see  href="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059">https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059

This page gives an answer which seems to be working for me.